# style property is not working in nested paragraph element

Tags: html, css, web

In the following html code ***the paragraph (p) element color is not changing with color property of css***  , *

> **but if i replace p with div element it is working properly..**

```
enter code here
```

How To Install Node.js and npm Tool in Ubuntu 14.04

## How To Install Node.js and npm Tool in Ubuntu 14.04

```
<div>
    <h2>
        Introduction:
    </h2>
    <p style="color:red;">
    <h3>Node.js</h3>
    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
    Nodejs is an open source , cross platform , JavaScript runtime environment  which is based on  <a href="https://developers.google.com/v8/"> Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine</a>.
    <br>
    Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient.<br><br>

    It is used to develop scalable, real-time , network and server-side applications written in javascript and we can run that applications within Node.js runtime environment  on Mac OS X ,Windows ,Linux ,solaris and BSD.<br><br>

    Node.js provides an event-driven architecture and a non-blocking I/O API designed to optimize an application's throughput and scalability for real-time web applications. It uses Google V8 JavaScript engine to execute code, and a large percentage of the basic modules are written in JavaScript. Node.js contains a built-in library to allow applications to act as a web server without software such as Apache HTTP Server, Nginx or IIS.<br><br>

    Node.js can be combined with a browser, a document database (such as MongoDB or CouchDB) and JSON for a unified JavaScript development stack.<br><br>

    According to wikipedia,

    Node.js is used by IBM, Microsoft, Yahoo!, Walmart, LinkedIn, Rakuten, PayPal and GoDaddy .

    </p>

    <p>
        <h3>npm</h3>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

    npm is the pre-installed package manager for the Node.js server platform. It is used to install Node.js programs from the npm registry, organizing the installation and management of third-party Node.js programs.
    </p>
</div>
```

**

> **the output for above code 
>   is**
>   **
>   [image]

---

> after replacing the first p element in above code with div element

---

output is
[image]

---

> why color property is not working in p element but worked in div
>   element (in above code)?

---

Comment: You've any external CSS framework linked?

Comment: no , i did not use any external css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<h3>` is a block element, and `<p>` can't contain block elements.  When you write this:

```
<p style="...">
    <h3>heading</h3>
    text
</p>
```

The browser won't allow the `<h3>` to exist inside the `<p>`, so it quietly *fixes* this by closing the `<p>` tag early, producing something like this:

```
<p style="...">
    </p><h3>heading</h3>
    text
```

It works fine when you use `<div>`, because `<div>` can contain other block elements like `<h3>`.

Just move the `<h3>` outside of the `<p>` and it should work fine.

Though I note that it's kind of silly to put all that text in a single `<p>` and use `<br><br>` to separate paragraphs!  You may want to put each paragraph in its own `<p>` tag, since that's what the "p" is short for  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a css rule, instead of using inline `styles` (preferably inside the `<head>` tag wrapped in `<style></style>`):

```
p {
  color: red;
}
```